# ANOVA - Assumption of Independence

Tags: anova, independence, assumptions

I am also a little bit confused about the assumption of independence.

I have the following situation:

- one continuous dependent variable (radiant power of a medical device)
- a few independent variables [age of the device (categorized), ...]

The researcher went to a lot of doctors' surgeries to investigate the radiant power of their device[s]. The issue is, that some practices had more than one device.

My question is whether it is still meaningful to apply a multi-factor ANOVA? Because I doubt that the observations taken from the same surgery are independent from each other.

Comment: How many practices are there? Did you get multiple measurements of each device?

Comment: I would say you might want to model it in the framework of ANCOVA or random effects. Such a situation is often referred to as "pseudo-replication", since your doubt is correct, the obs from the same surgery seem to be correlated. You might want to check mechanism to overcome this problem of pseudo-replication before trying to choose an analysis. If the data is not collected yet, this design should not be adopted.

Comment: Because a user has been kind enough to answer, please do not destroy your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your data won't be independent.  That means your confidence intervals will appear narrower than the correct width and your p-values will be incorrect.  If the radient power is conditionally normal, you should use a linear mixed effects model to assess this.

*One other note, you would do best not to categorize the age of the devices.  Use the actual ages as a continuous variable and use a continuous regression rather than an ANOVA.  This will give you more statistical power and a clearer answer to your question of interest.*